# Dual of SES of relative chain complexes is also an SES

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

In Algebraic Topology by Hatcher, p. 199,

> ... we first dualize the short exact sequence $$0 \to C_n(A) \xrightarrow{i} C_n(X) \xrightarrow{j} C_n(X,A) \to 0$$ by applying $\operatorname{Hom}(-,G)$ to get $$0 \to C^n(X,A;G) \xrightarrow{j^*} C^n(X;G) \xrightarrow{i^*} C^n(A;G) \to 0$$

Now, Hatcher shows this by a direct argument regarding elements of each chain. I tried a different approach, and thought it would be nice to show that this sequence is exact by proving the first Ext group of $C_n(X,A)$ vanishes. But it seems that I can't show this directly. $C_n(X,A)$ doesn't seem to be free, let alone projective. How can I show this algebraically, without going through an element-wise argument?

Comment: Why do you think it's not free? Anyway, there's no need for fancy homological algebra. The short exact sequence is split exact and this is preserved by any additive functor.

Comment: @Thorgott So it seems to depend on the actual definitions of $C_n(A)$ and $C_n(X)$, not from some general algebra fact. I wasn't so sure about the $C_n(X,A)$ not being free part to be honest.

Comment: Yes, it might be worth inventing an exact sequence of abelian groups so that the dual sequence is NOT exact.